# Finding out the value of the variable rather than address

Tags: powershell-2.0

This is a sample code from PowerShell:

```
$SPNAME = Read-Host "Please enter Server name with org-root/ls-<SNAME>"
$SN = Get-UcsBlade -AssignedToDn $SPNAME | select Serial
$ChassisID = Get-UcsBlade -AssignedToDn $SPNAME | select ChassisId
Write-Host $SN
Write-Host $ChassisID
$ChassisName = Get-UcsChassis $ChassisID | select UsrLbl
Write-Host $ChassisName
```

Here the output of the ChassisID is displayed as 1. I want it to display the variable value and not the ID value.

Comment: What do you mean by "the variable value"? Do you want the entire object that was originally returned from Get-UcsBlade? If so, why are you specifically adding a step where you grab just the ChassisId property out of the object?

Comment: When I keep my cursor on the $ChassisID, it displays three attributes which are Name,Type and Value of the variable.  The value shown by this variable is @{ChassisID=1} instead of just 1.  How do i fix the code so that it displays value as 1.

Comment: Your comment about "keep my cursor on" makes no sense - are you using some kind of IDE? I'm not sure where you get three properties; after your third line of code, `$ChassisID` will be a PSObject with one property (ChassisId). And do you want $ChassisID to be 1 (like you said in your comment), or is it already 1 (like you said in your question)? Please edit the question to clearly state *what you see* and *what you want to see instead.*